# ASP.NET VB SqlBulkCopy String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to use `SqlBulkCopy` to upload a data table into SQL Server.

I'm getting this error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

I'm using

```
sqlBulkcopy.WriteToServer(dtCustom)
```

The SQL Server column is defined as `nvarchar(50)`

I changed the column to `nvarchar(150)` and same problem

This line is causing the problems with the import:

```
Enter the Location of Inspection
```

The line is 32 characters

If I remove "on"  then it works and imports.

So what's the deal with a SQL Server table column defined as `nvarchar(50)` and 32 characters for data going into it?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are your columns in the same order in the source and destination?

Comment: The data is from an XML file.  The columns are in the same order as read in.  But the next XmlNode, after this one, is not added to the table at all.

The XML is read into a datatable (dtCustom).  Then the datatable is copied into the SQL table.

Comment: I have a similar issue. When you say: `if I remove "on" then it works and imports.`, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The columns have to be mapped.  Even though the datatable has the same column names as the SQL table - in the asp.net vb coding you still have to do column mappings.

Comment: adding the mappings fixed it for me as well.